# Minimize $x^2+6y^2+4z^2$ subject to $x+2y+z-4=0$ and $2x^2+y^2=16$

Tags: optimization, systems-of-equations, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima

Minimize $x^2+6y^2+4z^2$ subject to $x+2y+z-4=0$ and $2x^2+y^2=16$

My try:

By Lagrange Multiplier method we have

$$L(x,y,z,\lambda, \mu)=(x^2+6y^2+4z^2)+\lambda(x+2y+z-4)+\mu(2x^2+y^2-16)$$

For $$L_x=0$$ we get

$$2x+\lambda+4\mu x=0 \tag{1}$$

For $$L_y=0$$ we get

$$12y+2\lambda+2\mu y=0 \tag{2}$$

For $$L_z=0$$ we get

$$8z+\lambda=0 \tag{3}$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get

$$x=\frac{4 \lambda}{1-2\mu}$$

$$y=\frac{8 \lambda}{6-\mu}$$

Substituting $x$ , $y$ and $z$ above in constrainst we get

$$2 \frac{\lambda^2}{(1-2\mu)^2}+4 \frac{\lambda^2}{(6-\mu)^2}=1 \tag{4}$$

$$\frac{4 \lambda}{1-2\mu}+\frac{16 \lambda}{6-\mu}+\frac{\lambda}{8}=4 \tag{5}$$

But its tedious to solve above equations for $\lambda$ and $\mu$

Any other approach?

Comment: WLOG $\sqrt2x=4\cos t,y=4\sin t, z=?$

Comment: Good idea sir. we have $z=4-2\sqrt{2} \cos t-8 \sin t$. To minimize $f(t)=8\cos^2 t+96 \sin^2 t+4\left(4-2\sqrt{2} \cos t-8 \sin t \right)^2$. But this also seems lengthy

Comment: Try to solve equations $(4)$ and $(5)$ by setting  $\text{sin}(t) = \frac{\sqrt{2}\lambda}{1-2\mu}$ and  $\text{cos}(t) = \frac{2\lambda}{6-\mu}$. Hence, use trigonometric identities to reduce the problem to a quadratic equation on $\text{tan}(t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Let $u=x^2+6y^2+4(4-2y-x)^2$

$\iff5x^2-16(2-y)x+22y^2-16y+16-u=0$

As $x$ is real, the discriminant will be $\ge0$

$$\implies256(y-2)^2\ge20(22y^2-16y+16-u)$$

$$\implies64(y-2)^2\ge5(22y^2-16y+16-u)$$

$$\implies5u\ge46y^2-176y+176=46\left(y-\dfrac{44}{23}\right)^2+176-46\left(\dfrac{44}{23}\right)^2$$

Now $y^2=16-2x^2\le16\implies-4\le y\le4\iff-4-\dfrac{44}{23}\le y-\dfrac{44}{23}\le4-\dfrac{44}{23}$

Comment: Very nice approach

Answer (score 1):

Since you are assuming that $2x^2+y^2=16$, your problem is equivalent to the problem of minimizing $\frac{11}2y^2+4z^2$. But then your first equation becomes $\lambda+4\mu x=0$, which is much simpler.

Comment: Good ,so with your idea i got $x=\frac{-\lambda}{4 \mu}$, $y=\frac{-2\lambda}{2\mu+11}$, $z=\frac{-\lambda}{8}$. But i don't think its simple enough again?

Answer (score 0):

With computer I get numeric solution
$$f_{min}=9.445967377367024$$
if
$$x=2.811441051354938\\
y=0.4377195786259503\\
z=0.3131197913931612$$ 
Exact values of  $x,y,z$ is solutions of equations:
$$2033x^4-800x^3-13960x^2-1792x+6144=0,\\
2033y^4-6016y^3-27920y^2+88064y-32768=0,\\
2033z^4-19696z^3-84456z^2+176704z-46464=0.$$
We can solve these equations exact and get exact solutions. 
However, there are too big expressions.